# AbstractGoogleClient: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

Tags: android, google-api-client

```
06-06 00:05:02.955: I/DEBUG(5660): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-06 00:05:02.955: I/DEBUG(5660): Build fingerprint: 'google/occam/mako:4.2.2/JDQ39/573038:user/release-keys'
06-06 00:05:02.955: I/DEBUG(5660): Revision: '11'
06-06 00:05:02.955: I/DEBUG(5660): pid: 3787, tid: 3806, name: pool-1-thread-1  >>> com.example.android <<<
06-06 00:05:02.955: I/DEBUG(5660): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     r0 74e4ab1c  r1 ffffffff  r2 00000008  r3 7293e04d
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     r4 7293e04d  r5 7293e04e  r6 00000000  r7 7293e04d
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     r8 00000020  r9 7293e04d  sl 00000000  fp 74e4ab1c
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     ip 6f148da0  sp 74e4aa98  lr 6f1313c7  pc 406f4430  cpsr 00000030
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     d0  06332f7964707374  d1  6808322f79647074
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     d2  0820007433000070  d3  3261342f7964702f
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     d4  0011c000c6ea537e  d5  01ff000000003900
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     d6  0304000b00000100  d7  3300002300020100
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     d16 4040000000000000  d17 4040000000000000
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     d20 0000000000000000  d21 397377ce858a5d48
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     d22 3fa555555555554c  d23 bcb1a62633145c07
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     d26 0000002f0000002f  d27 0000002f0000002f
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     d28 0000000000000005  d29 0001000000010000
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     d30 0000000000000004  d31 0000000000000000
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     scr 60000090
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660): backtrace:
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     #00  pc 00022430  /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_select_next_proto+25)
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     #01  pc 000223c3  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     #02  pc 0002905f  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl_parse_serverhello_tlsext+458)
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     #03  pc 00015957  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl3_get_server_hello+894)
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     #04  pc 00018193  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl3_connect+618)
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     #05  pc 000235d7  /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_connect+18)
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     #06  pc 0001126b  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl23_connect+1970)
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     #07  pc 0002350f  /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_do_handshake+66)
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     #08  pc 00024c9d  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     #09  pc 0001e290  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     #10  pc 0004d411  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+396)
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     #11  pc 000276a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     #12  pc 0002b57c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     #13  pc 0005fc31  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     #14  pc 0005fc5b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     #15  pc 000547d7  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     #16  pc 0000e3d8  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     #17  pc 0000dac4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+160)
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660): stack:
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aa58  00000008  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aa5c  408da05b  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aa60  00000000  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aa64  6fcc4e58  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aa68  409093fa  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aa6c  00000000  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aa70  c0000000  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aa74  00000003  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aa78  00000003  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aa7c  00000000  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aa80  7294e6f8  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aa84  402673c3  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+5170)
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aa88  6fcb2af8  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aa8c  4089d1a5  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aa90  df0027ad  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aa94  00000000  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     #00  74e4aa98  6f1317f5  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aa9c  4089c03d  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aaa0  74e4ab1b  [stack:3806]
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aaa4  00000000  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aaa8  000a0088  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aaac  7254e480  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aab0  7293e04d  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aab4  74e4ab1b  [stack:3806]
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aab8  74e4ab1c  [stack:3806]
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aabc  7293e04d  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aac0  00003374  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aac4  74e4ab54  [stack:3806]
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aac8  407032bc  /system/lib/libssl.so
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aacc  6f1313c7  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     #01  74e4aad0  00000000  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aad4  ffffffff  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aad8  74e4ab1b  [stack:3806]
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aadc  7254e480  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aae0  00000009  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aae4  6f131397  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aae8  00000020  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aaec  406fb061  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl_parse_serverhello_tlsext+460)
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):     #02  74e4aaf0  00000020  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aaf4  00000000  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aaf8  00000075  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4aafc  00000001  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4ab00  7293e06d  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4ab04  407032bc  /system/lib/libssl.so
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4ab08  00000001  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4ab0c  7293e06d  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4ab10  74e4ab50  [stack:3806]
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4ab14  7293e069  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4ab18  00001170  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4ab1c  00000100  
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4ab20  40934eb8  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
06-06 00:05:03.055: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4ab24  7254e480  
06-06 00:05:03.065: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4ab28  00000061  
06-06 00:05:03.065: I/DEBUG(5660):          74e4ab2c  00000000  
06-06 00:05:03.065: I/DEBUG(5660):          ........  ........
06-06 00:05:03.065: I/DEBUG(5660): memory near r0:
06-06 00:05:03.065: I/DEBUG(5660): memory near r3:
06-06 00:05:03.075: I/DEBUG(5660): memory near r4:
06-06 00:05:03.325: I/BootReceiver(505): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_09 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
06-06 00:05:03.345: I/WindowState(505): WIN DEATH: Window{4257c2b8 u0 com.example.android/com.example.android.MainActivity_}
06-06 00:05:03.345: I/ActivityManager(505): Process com.example.android (pid 3787) has died.
```

Symbolized:

```
RELADDR   FUNCTION                                                                                                            FILE:LINE
00022430  SSL_select_next_proto+26                                                                                            external/openssl/ssl/ssl_lib.c:1583
000223c3  next_proto_select_callback(ssl_st*, unsigned char**, unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, void*)+44  libcore/luni/src/main/native/org_apache_harmony_xnet_provider_jsse_NativeCrypto.cpp:3402
0002905f  ssl_parse_serverhello_tlsext+458                                                                                    external/openssl/ssl/t1_lib.c:1541
00015957  ssl3_get_server_hello+894                                                                                           external/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c:1103
00018193  ssl3_connect+618                                                                                                    external/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c:306
000235d7  SSL_connect+18                                                                                                      external/openssl/ssl/ssl_lib.c:948
v------>  ssl23_get_server_hello                                                                                              external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:783
0001126b  ssl23_connect+1970                                                                                                  external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:226
0002350f  SSL_do_handshake+66                                                                                                 external/openssl/ssl/ssl_lib.c:2577
00024c9d  NativeCrypto_SSL_do_handshake(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, int, _jobject*, _jobject*, int, unsigned char, _jbyteArray*)+252  libcore/luni/src/main/native/org_apache_harmony_xnet_provider_jsse_NativeCrypto.cpp:3558
0001e290  dvmPlatformInvoke+112                                                                                               dalvik/vm/arch/arm/CallEABI.S:258
0004d411  dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+396                                          dalvik/vm/Jni.cpp:1155
000276a0  dalvik_mterp+20                                                                                                     dalvik/vm/mterp/out/InterpAsm-armv7-a-neon.S:16240
0002b57c  dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184                                                                   dalvik/vm/interp/Interp.cpp:1956
0005fc31  dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272                                  dalvik/vm/interp/Stack.cpp:526
0005fc5b  dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20                                                     dalvik/vm/interp/Stack.cpp:429
000547d7  interpThreadStart(void*)+158                                                                                        dalvik/vm/Thread.cpp:1538
0000e3d8  __thread_entry+72                                                                                                   bionic/libc/bionic/pthread.c:204
0000dac4  pthread_create+160                                                                                                  bionic/libc/bionic/pthread.c:348
```

And than the app crashes. Google Drive API Client Library.

Comment: Are you sure the jar is making it into the build?  Are you installing on a device / emulator image which supports this?

Comment: Hardware devices (Nexus 4) which definitly supports it

Comment: The Problem with the Dex optimization is fixed (I had to download the play services library again) however, the app still crashes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the bug.
After implementing the whole Google Drive Api by my own with the Apache HTTP client I also received those weired crash.
As a result it wasn't the Google Drive API which was buggy.

I'm using the Picasso Library for fetching images in several adapters.
Picasso uses the OkHttp Library to fetch those images. OkHttp seems to change something on the SSL context which causes all HTTPClients to behave pretty strange.

You can find a discussion and solution here:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/184

Comment: Thanks for your research! We were having the same problem, having recently started using the picasso.jar + okhttp.jar as well.

Comment: +1 Jeez this was causing me a headache - would not have found this - many thanks

Comment: Run into the same issue trying to get Google Analytics (v 3.0.1) to work. The solution at GitHub fixed it; I used [this](https://github.com/UweTrottmann/getglue-java/commit/1be1a6ddea933c5f4f38d212775432c8cfbc413f) specifically. (Also, despite subsequent ["Service unavailable (code=1)" warnings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707380/google-analytics-v3-for-android-service-unavailable-code-1-using-local-store) it was actually working.)