# Android: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1) in getOutputStream

Tags: java, android, java-7, segmentation-fault

After update to jdk 7 my application builds began to crash with this error. There is no stack traces so very hard to figure out what's wrong.

At first I found that it usually means OOM and related to images. Changing `NetworkImageView`  to `ImageView` with Picasso helped. But now I faced this problem once again in uploading file to server.

Here is a piece of code:

```
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", mCookieString);
conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", "image" + mIndex + ".jpg");

OutputStream dos = conn.getOutputStream(); // here is the crash
```

When using Apache `HttpClient` the result is the same

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
entity.addPart(new StringPart("type", mImageType.code));
entity.addPart(new FilePart("file",
    readContent(mImagePath.getContentStream()),
    mImagePath.generateFileName(mIndex),
    mImagePath.getContentType()));

HttpPost post = new HttpPost(Api.url(Api.Methods.UPLOAD_IMAGE));
post.addHeader(new BasicHeader("Cookie", mCookieString));
post.setEntity(entity);

try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post); // crash here
    …

} catch (IOException e) {
    …
}
```

Log:

```
10-21 21:44:44.793  22098-22193/com.drive2 A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 22193 (Thread-7029)
10-21 21:44:44.843      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-21 21:44:44.843      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'google/occam/mako:4.4.4/KTU84P/1227136:user/release-keys'
10-21 21:44:44.843      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ Revision: '11'
10-21 21:44:44.843      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 22098, tid: 22193, name: Thread-7029  >>> com.drive2 <<<
10-21 21:44:44.843      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.953      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 4b723065  r3 00000009
10-21 21:44:44.953      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ r4 00000008  r5 4b723066  r6 00000000  r7 ffffffff
10-21 21:44:44.953      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ r8 00000001  r9 00000020  sl 00000009  fp 4b723065
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ ip 472e7b34  sp 4dce5460  lr 472dc0b5  pc 40a61fae  cpsr 600f0030
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ d4  bab40e046bf201fc  d5  078369f6ac49e38b
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ d6  762afdb2066e0a4f  d7  13c0670fd2ea880f
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ d16 0000000000000000  d17 0000000000000000
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ d18 4dadc2491e1e278b  d19 f8da636cf9db7d0c
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ d20 3ff0000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ d24 3f699999a0000000  d25 0000000000000000
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ d26 3ff0000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ d28 3f699999a0000000  d29 0000000000000000
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ scr 60000013
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ backtrace:
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00  pc 00026fae  /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_select_next_proto+49)
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01  pc 000070b1  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02  pc 0002f373  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl_parse_serverhello_tlsext+434)
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ #03  pc 00018129  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl3_get_server_hello+1008)
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ #04  pc 00017527  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl3_connect+566)
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ #05  pc 00027d4b  /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_do_handshake+50)
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ #06  pc 0000aedd  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ #07  pc 0045cf54  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@boot.oat
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ stack:
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5420  61072760  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@boot.oat
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5424  fa171053
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5428  00000002
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce542c  472dbfed  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5430  00000002
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5434  472dbfed  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5438  00000003
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce543c  40a31e64  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5440  400aa1b8
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5444  40a31e64  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5448  4a1abf98  [anon:libc_malloc]
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce544c  4006ce6b  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+4254)
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5450  00000003
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5454  0301d844
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5458  4006bdcd  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc)
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce545c  00000003
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00  4dce5460  40a31e64  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5464  4dce54e0  [stack:22193]
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5468  4dce54dc  [stack:22193]
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce546c  4b723065  [anon:libc_malloc]
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5470  00000009
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5474  4b723065  [anon:libc_malloc]
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5478  4dce54dc  [stack:22193]
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce547c  4dce54e0  [stack:22193]
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5480  4a1abf50  [anon:libc_malloc]
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5484  4c838910  [anon:libc_malloc]
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5488  00000020
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce548c  00000009
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5490  4b723061  [anon:libc_malloc]
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5494  472dc0b5  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01  4dce5498  00000000
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce549c  ffffffff
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54a0  4b72306e  [anon:libc_malloc]
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54a4  4dce5518  [stack:22193]
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54a8  4dce5518  [stack:22193]
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54ac  4b723065  [anon:libc_malloc]
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54b0  00003374
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54b4  40a6a375  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl_parse_serverhello_tlsext+436)
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02  4dce54b8  00000009
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54bc  00000000
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54c0  40a72634  /system/lib/libssl.so
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54c4  00000000
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54c8  00000001
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54cc  4dce551c  [stack:22193]
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54d0  4b72306a  [anon:libc_malloc]
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54d4  4b72306e  [anon:libc_malloc]
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54d8  4c838910  [anon:libc_malloc]
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54dc  4a0fedf0  [anon:libc_malloc]
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54e0  40a2fdc0  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54e4  4c838910  [anon:libc_malloc]
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54e8  00000062
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54ec  4b72300c  [anon:libc_malloc]
10-21 21:44:44.963      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54f0  4b72302f  [anon:libc_malloc]
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54f4  40a77190  /system/lib/libssl.so
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ ........  ........
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near r2:
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723044 2afdb206 ea880f76 c0670fd2 1a000013
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723054 010001ff 000b0000 01000304 00743302
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723064 74680809 312f7074 0000312e 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723074 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723084 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723094 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b7230a4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b7230b4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b7230c4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b7230d4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b7230e4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b7230f4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723104 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723114 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723124 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723134 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near r5:
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723044 2afdb206 ea880f76 c0670fd2 1a000013
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723054 010001ff 000b0000 01000304 00743302
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723064 74680809 312f7074 0000312e 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723074 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723084 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723094 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b7230a4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b7230b4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b7230c4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b7230d4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b7230e4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b7230f4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723104 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723114 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723124 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723134 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near fp:
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723044 2afdb206 ea880f76 c0670fd2 1a000013
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723054 010001ff 000b0000 01000304 00743302
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723064 74680809 312f7074 0000312e 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723074 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723084 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723094 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b7230a4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b7230b4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b7230c4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b7230d4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b7230e4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b7230f4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723104 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723114 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723124 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4b723134 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.974      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near ip:
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472e7b14 409c76e1 4098baf9 409bdd21 409bd9c5
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472e7b24 409be70d 409b69cd 409c1d41 4006f021
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472e7b34 40a61f7d 4006a7dc 4006a8e0 409d5091
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472e7b44 40a617f5 400b7927 400583b1 402305b5
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472e7b54 409ca19d 409c2a49 409c28b5 409c2851
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472e7b64 409c2dd9 409c4ec9 40081235 409c4ea9
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472e7b74 409c4f8d 40069c01 4006f415 4006def5
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472e7b84 402306f5 40a61ff9 40a64f1d 409fcbfd
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472e7b94 409955f5 409956dd 409fcc45 40998799
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472e7ba4 4098ea29 4099125d 409fc385 409efef9
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472e7bb4 409972f5 4099aa5d 409caad9 4099ab01
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472e7bc4 4098a905 409cb135 409baf01 409bb265
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472e7bd4 409baa5d 409bac69 409bb09d 409ba9d9
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472e7be4 409bae8d 409d4f39 409bae99 409bae91
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472e7bf4 409bad6d 409cc839 409cc73d 409ccb79
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472e7c04 4098bb01 409bb365 409899a1 40994b61
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near sp:
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5440 400aa1b8 40a31e64 4a1abf98 4006ce6b
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5450 00000003 0301d844 4006bdcd 00000003
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5460 40a31e64 4dce54e0 4dce54dc 4b723065
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5470 00000009 4b723065 4dce54dc 4dce54e0
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5480 4a1abf50 4c838910 00000020 00000009
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5490 4b723061 472dc0b5 00000000 ffffffff
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54a0 4b72306e 4dce5518 4dce5518 4b723065
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54b0 00003374 40a6a375 00000009 00000000
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54c0 40a72634 00000000 00000001 4dce551c
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54d0 4b72306a 4b72306e 4c838910 4a0fedf0
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54e0 40a2fdc0 4c838910 00000062 4b72300c
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce54f0 4b72302f 40a77190 00000020 00001000
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5500 00001110 40a5312d 4dce5518 4dce5514
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5510 4c838910 00000001 4a1abf50 4b723052
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5520 4c838910 00001120 4a1abf50 472dc201
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4dce5530 00000000 00001120 00001110 40a5252b
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ code around pc:
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40a61f8c d02c2b00 9f0f9701 21009102 4001f81b
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40a61f9c 0801f101 eb0bb1cf eb0b0001 90030508
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40a61fac f8162000 f1009000 454c0a01 eb06d109
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40a61fbc 4628010a f7e54622 4601ef50 29002001
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40a61fcc eb0ad00a 42b80009 eb08d3eb 9a040104
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40a61fdc 42912002 e000d3da 99029e03 1c729f01
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40a61fec 7832603a b005700a 8ff0e8bd 3178f8d0
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40a61ffc 2100600b bf182b00 117cf890 47706011
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40a6200c 11a4f8c0 21a8f8c0 bf004770 11acf8c0
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40a6201c 21b0f8c0 bf004770 4605b570 f8d54614
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40a6202c 460e01bc bf182800 edc6f7e5 f240480a
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40a6203c 490a6296 44014478 f7e54620 2101edb2
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40a6204c 01bcf8c5 4631b130 f7e54622 2100edf2
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40a6205c 41c0f8c5 bd704608 00013a04 ffffb63d
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40a6206c 4605b570 f8d54614 460e019c bf182800
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40a6207c eda2f7e5 f240480a 490a62aa 44014478
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ code around lr:
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472dc094 46072121 f7fe4640 6a7aef8c b1646abb
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472dc0a4 000ce88d 46294630 9b084622 ef68f7fe
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472dc0b4 bf142801 20002003 b116e004 6034b10d
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472dc0c4 2003702c 81fce8bd 4604b538 6a05b188
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472dc0d4 f7ffb155 6829ffc3 6d9a6803 46284790
10-21 21:44:44.984      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472dc0e4 ef6cf7fe 62202000 20012100 616160e1
10-21 21:44:44.994      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472dc0f4 bd38bd38 6803b508 47906d5a b508bd08
10-21 21:44:44.994      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472dc104 6dda6803 bd084790 6803b508 47906fda
10-21 21:44:44.994      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472dc114 b510bd08 f8d46804 47a04084 b40cbd10
10-21 21:44:44.994      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472dc124 ab04b513 f8536804 f8d42b04 930140c8
10-21 21:44:44.994      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472dc134 e8bd47a0 b002401c b40c4770 ab04b513
10-21 21:44:44.994      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472dc144 f8536804 f8d42b04 930140f8 e8bd47a0
10-21 21:44:44.994      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472dc154 b002401c b40c4770 ab04b513 f8536804
10-21 21:44:44.994      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472dc164 f8d42b04 930141cc e8bd47a0 b002401c
10-21 21:44:44.994      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472dc174 b5084770 f8d36803 4790229c b508bd08
10-21 21:44:44.994      171-171/? I/DEBUG﹕ 472dc184 f8d36803 479022ac b510bd08 f8d46804
```

What can be wrong here? Why it is happened after jdk update? What else can break?

Comment: I would use apache http client for server communication...

Comment: I've tried and got the same result

Comment: Need more details about your actual environment. Why did you tag this [tag:android]? Is this running in an Android emulator?

Comment: It is running on device. Devices are different – Nexus 4, Nexus 7 and two more

Comment: If it is running on the Android device, then post the stack trace.  But don't begin your question with "my application builds began to crash" as that makes it sound like the build process itself (which incorporates a lot of Java running on the development machine) is failing.

Comment: A segfault, especially in a routine call like that, indicates some bug in native code. Which implementation specifically is the problem in?

Comment: @chrylis - no, it more typically indicates native code being given bad inputs.  That error is basically the native version of a null pointer exception.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Please read question before answering. There is no stack trace, and errors like this usually don't have stack traces. And yes, it seems to be build issue, because this code was working and stopped working after jdk update. So what?

Comment: OK, I've added fingerprint. Is that what you call stack trace? Can it be helpful?

Comment: Yes, this strack trace is useful - it suggests you have the same issue with something grabbing and altering the global SSL setup as discussed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16950492/abstractgoogleclient-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv

Comment: @ChrisStratton A well-behaved native method should be throwing `NullPointerException` on a `null` input. A segfault from anything below the top-level wrapper is a bug in the native library.

Comment: @chrylis - no.  A NullPointerException is a java Object. There's no reason for native code to generate one.  As described in the link, the issue **is not a bug in the native library** but rather misbehavior by application code, which corrupts the global process state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @ChrisStratton for pointing me. Here is working code.
Now I don't understand how it worked earlier.

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
try {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, null, null);
    okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
} catch (GeneralSecurityException ignored) {
}

// open a URL connection to the Servlet
fileInputStream = mImagePath.getContentStream();
URL url = new URL(Api.url(Api.Methods.UPLOAD_IMAGE));

conn = okHttpClient.open(url); // FIX!!!
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

Comment: "Swankjesse" seems to have explained the why before proposing the code you are using: "When OkHttp enables NPN for its own SPDY-related stuff, it ends up turning on NPN for the singleton shared SSL socket factory. Later when HttpURLConnection attempts to do SSL, it freaks out and crashes because NPN is enabled when it isn't expected to be. A simple immediate workaround for OkHttp is to configure the client to create its own SSL context rather than using the system default."